# How do I make that the label text stays as Question and doesn`t change for Java Swing?

Tags: java

So, basically, I have this code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Frame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    int count = 0, current = 0, x = 0, y = 0, now = 0;
    String q;
    JFrame frame;
    JRadioButton radiobuttons[] = new JRadioButton[3];
    JLabel label;
    JButton button;
    Frame(){
        ButtonGroup group1 = new ButtonGroup();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            radiobuttons[i] = new JRadioButton();
            add(radiobuttons[i]);
            group1.add(radiobuttons[i]);
        }

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Did you...?");
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
        radiobuttons[0].setBounds(50, 300, 200, 50);
        radiobuttons[1].setBounds(275, 300, 200, 50);
        radiobuttons[2].setBounds(500, 300, 200, 50);
        radiobuttons[0].setFocusable(false);
        radiobuttons[1].setFocusable(false);
        radiobuttons[2].setFocusable(false);
        label = new JLabel();
        label.setText("<html>I have some questions for you. <bg>  Wouldn`t mind answering?");
        label.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.CENTER_BASELINE, 40));
        label.setBounds(90, 50, 600, 300);
        label.setForeground(Color.lightGray);
        label.setBackground(Color.blue);
        frame.add(label);
        label.setVisible(true);
        button = new JButton("Next");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        button.setBounds(330, 400, 100, 50);
        frame.add(button);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    void setData(){
        if (current == 0){
            label.setText("<html>Question 1: <bg>What is the name of Gojo`s domain expansion?");
            frame.add(radiobuttons[0]);
            frame.add(radiobuttons[1]);
            frame.add(radiobuttons[2]);
            radiobuttons[0].setText("Unlimited Void");
            radiobuttons[1].setText("Coffin of the Iron Mountain");
            radiobuttons[2].setText("Self-Embodiment of Perfection");
        }
        if (current == 1){
            label.setText("<html>Great! Question 2: <bg>Who is the best waifu in jjk?");
            radiobuttons[0].setText("Maki");
            radiobuttons[1].setText("Maki");
            radiobuttons[2].setText("Maki");
        }
        if (current == 2){
            label.setBounds(90, 10, 600, 200);
            label.setText("<html>Good job! Question 3: <bg>What kind of Woman is your type?");
            radiobuttons[0].setBounds(50, 200, 400, 50);
            radiobuttons[1].setBounds(50, 275, 400, 50);
            radiobuttons[2].setBounds(50, 350, 200, 50);
            radiobuttons[0].setText("As long as she has unshakable character, I wont ask for more");
            radiobuttons[1].setText("A tall woman with a big ass, like Jennifer Lawrence");
            radiobuttons[2].setText("Men");
        }
        if (current == 3){
            label.setBounds(90, 50, 600, 300);
            label.setText("And the final question...");
        }
        if (current == 4){
            label.setBounds(90, 50, 600, 300);
            label.setText("Will you watch Jujutsu Kaisen?");
            radiobuttons[0].setText("Yes!");
            radiobuttons[1].setText("Of Course!");
            radiobuttons[2].setText("No!");
        }
        }

    boolean chackAns(){
        if (current == 0){
            return (radiobuttons[0].isSelected());
        }
        if (current == 1){
            return true;
        }
        if (current == 2){
        return (radiobuttons[1].isSelected());}
         if (current == 3){
             return true;
         }
         if (current== 4){
             if (radiobuttons[2].isSelected()){
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Say bye-bye to your Disk C", "You will pay", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                 System.exit(0);
             } if (radiobuttons[1].isSelected() || radiobuttons[0].isSelected()){
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Alright! I caught you on your words!", "Ok", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                 System.exit(0);
             }
         }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == button){
            if (chackAns()){
                current+=1;
            }
            setData();}
        if (current == 2){
            if (radiobuttons[0].isSelected()){
                label.setText("<html>I knew that... <bg>You`re boring, Fushiguro *freaking slams to the ground*");
            }
            if (radiobuttons[2].isSelected()){
                label.setText("Dude...");
            }
        }

        if (current == 3){
                radiobuttons[0].setBounds(1000, 1000, 20, 20);
                radiobuttons[1].setBounds(1000, 1000, 20, 20);
                radiobuttons[2].setBounds(1000, 1000, 20, 20);
            }
            if (current == 4){
                radiobuttons[0].setBounds(50, 300, 200, 50);
                radiobuttons[1].setBounds(275, 300, 200, 50);
                radiobuttons[2].setBounds(500, 300, 200, 50);
            }
            }

            }
```

I was trying to make a quiz in which only right answers will move you forward in questions but when I tried to write funny lines for wrong answers in question 3, they would keep appearing instead of question itself if the corresponding radiobutton was selected for previous question. I dont really know how to explain this any better, but I guess you can try to run it and see what I mean

I want it to set the funny text only when you specifically select the corresponding radiobutton after the question appears. Any help is welcome and I could really use some grammar correction and adjusting for code since I`m really new to this stuff and I dont know a lot of things that people use to make their code better-looking. Again, any help would be appreciated and thank you all.

Comment: *frame.setLayout(null);* Is nearly always wrong [Avoid null layouts in Swing](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/114-avoid-null-layouts-in-swing)
What you're looking for is a [`CardLayout`](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/64-java-login-with-cardlayout) Tearing your own gui down is also nearly always wrong

Comment: I ran your code. Pardon me but I don't see where the problem is. Maybe you can [edit] your question and post some screen captures showing what your GUI currently displays and what you want it to display.